# Session share between ASP and WCF

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, session, ninject

We tried sharing the same session for a ASP application and a WCF service.
In the past, we set up a POC, which worked OK. We were able to have the same session in both ASP as in WCF. But now, when we tried implementing the POC in our current project, we're not able to retrieve the same session.

The way we done this is:

1) Session enabled by powershell command

2) Add values to web.config

- Same machineKey
- Same SessionState (mode SQLServer)
- Same httpModule (which configures the same session, session-application)
- Same modules (pointing to same module as httpModule)
- <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />

**In addition:**

- On both ASP and WCF, we have a session (from HttpContext.Current.Session), but they are different (for
  example sessionID is different)
- When debugging, the module is only triggered on ASP side, thus the problem is likely in the WCF
- We use Ninject our application (not in POC) but we bind the module in the bootstrapper

**FYI:**

```
public class SharedSessionModule : IHttpModule
{
    public void Init(HttpApplication context)
    {
        try
        {
            string appName = Configuration.Session.AppName;
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(appName)) return;

            var runtimeInfo = typeof (HttpRuntime).GetField("_theRuntime", BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
            var theRuntime = (HttpRuntime) runtimeInfo.GetValue(null);
            var appNameInfo = typeof (HttpRuntime).GetField("_appDomainAppId", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
            appNameInfo.SetValue(theRuntime, appName);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //Logging
        }
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        // Nothing to dispose.
    }
}
```

Anybody who has an idea what the problem might be? (I think it might be when I use Ninject, WCF)

Comment: What is POC? Proof-of-Concept? Then, are these two different applications or you have the WCF in the same app? Also, how do you expect the session is shared if SessionIDs are different? What clients call both the ASP and WCF (the same client or two different clients)?

Comment: POC = Proof of concept. These are to different applications, running in a different application pool. To be more specific, the ASP.NET is actually a SharePoint site. The problem is the sessionID's are the same. If the same session should be shared, the sessionID should be the same, but in this case they aren't.

Comment: The same client calls both ASP and WCF. More specific: The user calls ASP, but on the page, there are ajax calls to the WCF/REST service to retrieve data.